# How to pass credentials through AWS parameter store in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, aws-parameter-store

My organization wants to place every config data to be fetched from Parameter Store. I know we can use **AWS Secrets Manager Credentials Provider** plugin to get credentials using the secret manager. But I need to know how can we do the same when we use the same thing using parameter store.

I tried 2 methods, in the environment,

1. Using **AWS Parameter Store Build Wrapper**, but I'm not able to put it inside the environment stage. I'm able to declare these values inside withAWSParameterStore body
2. I tried giving CLI and running it on stages but it is giving me  the below error:
   *An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetParameter operation: Parameter name: can't be prefixed with "ssm" (case-insensitive). If formed as a path, it can consist of sub-paths divided by slash symbol; each sub-path can be formed as a mix of letters, numbers and the following 3 symbols .-_*

Any help would be very helpful.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        Username=  'aws ssm get-parameter --name "apple" --query Parameter.Value'
    }
    stages {
    stage('Testing parametestore'){

        steps {
            withAWSParameterStore(namePrefixes: "/IP",recursive: true){ echo "My parameter value is ${IP_DEV1}" 
            script {
            echo "Testing Parameter Store"
            sh '''#!/bin/bash 
            echo "My parameter value is ${IP_DEV1}" 
            '''

                }


            }
            sh '''${SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}'''
            }
        }

  }
}
```